# Insert character after every nth character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to convert a number like: 1215464565 into 12-15-46-45-65. I'm trying to do this:

```
var num = 1215464565; 
num = num.toString();
num.replace(/(.{2)/g,"-1");
```

The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gm7krxzw/41/), however doesn't reflect this change though.

Comment: `num = num.replace(/(.{2})/g,"-1");`

Comment: @Regent It won't work.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it works (all pairs of digits are replaced with "-1" in `1215464565`). If you ask what is the point to replace pairs of digits with "-1" while hyphens between pairs of digits are required - I don't know, I just fixed OP code line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var num = 1215464565; 
var newNum = num.toString().match(/.{2}/g).join('-');
console.log(newNum);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/w2aa51ng/3)**

Comment: IMHO this is the most readable solution! +1

Comment: pretty cool, good to go!

Comment: This only works if `num` is exactly divisible by the split number otherwise the last block is missed off use `match(/.{1,2}/g` to ensure the last chars are shown.

Comment: If the string is empty then this throws an error `match(/.{0,2}/g).join(' ').trim().replace(/\s/g, '-');` works for empty strings, one character strings and everything after that. But we are getting a bit verbose.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below regex in `replace` function

```
(?!^)(\d{2})(?=(?:\d{2})*$)
```

and then replace the matched digits with `-$1`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hG2oH8/1)

```
> var num = 1215464565;
undefined
> num = num.toString();
'1215464565'
> num.replace(/(?!^)(\d{2})(?=(?:\d{2})*$)/g, '-$1')
'12-15-46-45-65'
```

Regular Expression:

```
(?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
  ^                        the beginning of the string
)                        end of look-ahead
(                        group and capture to \1:
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
)                        end of \1
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                           times):
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
  )*                       end of grouping
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                           the string
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
var num = 1215464565; 
num = num.toString();
for(var i = 2; i < num.length; i = i + 2)
{
    num = [num.slice(0, i), "-", num.slice(i)].join('');
    i++;
}
window.alert("" + num);
```