# Masking the input credit card number on client side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have a ViewModel containing a  string CreditCard. What I am looking for is an attribute or masking it in a way that in every 4 digits one space is added . Something like this:
4764 4000 9425 3041
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should probably wait to ask your question until you have made an attempt at this and have code to share along with a specific question about an error or problem with your code.

Comment: Try searching for some kind of jQuery / CSS input masking techniques and implement a blanking/ starring out code. Maybe there is a plugin that does that but needs more searching. You could just write some javascript your self to do this, when a value typed in, it moves that value to a hidden input and * out the visible one. And the same when deleting.

Comment: have you tried to use this https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: or https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask   or https://codepen.io/estelle/pen/LVQLRq ?

Comment: are you asking for c# or javascript? I dont think your task is related with asp.net-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with javascript:

```
var num = 1215464565; 
var newNum = num.toString().match(/.{4}/g).join(' ');
console.log(newNum);
```

[RelatedPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910567/insert-character-after-every-nth-character)

Answer (score 1):

Robin Herbot's jQuery input mask (https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) seems to do what you're looking for. You can specify the mask formatting in javascript or put it as an attribute.

```
<input id="cc" type="text" data-inputmask="'mask': '9999 9999 9999 9999'" />
```

Here is a codepen example (disclaimer not mine, credit to: Chris Coyier):

https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/PbOEqL

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const num = 4764400094253041;
const regex = /\d{4}/g;

const res = num.toString().replace(regex, (maths) => maths === 12 ? maths : maths + ' ')

const responseEl = document.getElementById("response");

responseEl.innerText = res;
```

```html
<div id="response"></div>
```